# jquery each() only looping through asp.net gridview once

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to loop through a gridview and throw an alert to the user if they haven't filled out the quantity on the item they have checked. But it only works on the first checkbox, and it doesn't return false because the code still executes on the server side.

```
function GetCheckedRows() {
    var checkBox = $("#flexCheckBoxList")
    var textBox = $("#flexTextBox")
    $("#flexGridView tr").each(function () {
        if ($(checkBox).is(':checked')) {
            if (textBox.val().length === 0) {
                alert("You must specify the amount needed");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Completed! Wanted to show the finished code that loops through and stops when something isn't correct. I had to create a variable to stop loop execution. This not only checks for an empty value but checks if it is a number too.

```
function GetCheckedRows() {
    var exitSubmit = false;
    $(".gridView tr").each(function (e) {
        var checkBox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
        var textBox = $(this).find("input[type='text']");
            if (checkBox.is(':checked')) {
                if (textBox.val().length === 0 || !$.isNumeric($(textBox).val())) {
                    exitSubmit = true;
                    return false;
            }
            else {
            return true;
            }
        }
    });
    if (exitSubmit) {
       alert("Please enter a valid amount");
       return false;
}
```

}

Comment: its because you are using id to loop make them as class and try to loop

Comment: The function you have posted is insufficient to stop a form post. It simply returns a true/false, which does NOTHING to the UI unless you have hijacked the click event properly, like `<a href="thing" onclick="return GetCheckedRows();">click!</a>`. Please post the rest of your code, specifically the ASPX of the GridView.

Comment: showing the gridview markup would be more convenient, IMHO.

Comment: @Graham He doesn't mention submitting a form.  He could be doing anything after this validation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Here is the markup for the button

Comment: <asp:Button ID="requestButton" runat="server" Text="Proceed With Request" CssClass="requestButton" ValidationGroup="requestButton" OnClientClick="return GetCheckedRows();" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your script so that you find the checkbox and textbox on the row that you are finding with `each()`...

```
function GetCheckedRows() {
    $("#flexGridView tr").each(function () {
        var $checkBox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
        var $textBox = $(this).find("input[type='text']");
        if ($checkBox.is(':checked')) {
            if ($textBox.val().length === 0) {
                alert("You must specify the amount needed");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If the checkbox and textbox have classes then it would make more sense to use them in the selectors, rather than inputs (as there may be other checkboxes and text boxes in each row - I don't know).

Also, your question suggests that you use the same ID for multiple checkboxes and multiple textboxes.  IDs must be unique - you can't use them to select multiple elements, like you can with classes.

Comment: Great! This solved my issue when I changed the input[type='textbox'] to text

Answer (score 3):

Use the jquery context selector to select thec check box within each row,like this:

```
function GetCheckedRows() {
$("#flexGridView tr").each(function () {
var $this = $(this), $checkBox = $("#flexCheckBoxList", $this);
    if ($checkBox.is(':checked')) {
        if (textBox.val().length === 0) {
            alert("You must specify the amount needed");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

give you `CheckBoxes` a class like `flexCheckBox` and you `TextBoxes` `flexTextBox`

```
function GetCheckedRows() {
    var checkBox = null;
    var textBox = null;
    $("#flexGridView tr").each(function () {
        checkBox = $(this).find(".flexCheckBox");
        textBox = $(this).find(".flexTextBox");
        if (checkBox.is(':checked')) {
            if (textBox.val().length === 0) {
                alert("You must specify the amount needed");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```